# Memory issue when freeing 2D arrays

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, gdb

2D Array creation phase :

```
int **table = new int*[10];
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    table[a] = new int[10];
    for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++){
        table[a][b] = 0;
    }
}
```

2D Array deletion phase :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    delete [] table[i];
}
delete [] table;
```

I noticed something while debugging my code with GDB. All values from table[0][0] to table[0][3] are garbage but all values from table[0][4] to table[0][9] are all 0. This problem is Valid for all pointers from table[0] to table[9].

Then I thought there was a problem with GDB and I printed table[0][0] and table[0][5] to the screen. Indeed the value of table[0][0] is garbage, the value of table[0][5] is 0.

My question is does c++ actually freeing this data?

Comment: Freeing allocated memory just means it's available for future use elsewhere. It may or may not be immediately reused. The compiler doesn't go out of its way to deliberately overwrite it with garbage; the original values may still sit there for some time, until some other part of the program happens to reuse the memory and write something else there.

Comment: *but all values from table[0][4] to table[0][9] are all 0.* -- Why do you believe that 0 is not a "garbage value" also?  Just because a value looks "nice" doesn't mean it is valid.  A `0` can be just as invalid as `-234362`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the data is actually being freed. If you dereference a pointer after its value is freed, you get undefined behaviour which might be its original value or some other garbage value.